# ARIMA, p and q identification. Please help

Tags: arima, regression-coefficients

I am very new to SARIMA and I am really facing a poblem which p,q,P,Q to use. Here is ACF and PACF of first-difference, two first plots (stationary) and ACF and PACF of first-seasonal difference (two last plots).

[image]

I think that P=1, Q=1 because ACF and PACF of first-seasonal difference drop off at lag 1 and are outside the confidence band. What about p and q ? Can I san that p=2 and q=2 because it drop of at lag 2? Or should I take under consideration the fact that only at lag 4 ACF and PACF are outside confidence band? Is p=4 and q=4 or 2 for both?

Or should I do AIC test for (2,1,2)(1,1,1)12, (4,1,2)(1,1,1)12, (2,1,4)(1,1,1)12, (4,1,4)(1,1,1)12 and check which one has the smallest? Or assuming that p=2 and q=2 does not make any sense because its within the confidence band?

SARIMA (4,1,4)(1,1,1)12 gives me  lots of non-significant coefficients. :
[image]

Or maybe should I try SARIMA(7,1,4)(1,1,1)12, SARIMA(8,1,4)(1,1,1)12 ? But it really does not seem reasonable.

Please tell me what to do now :(
Thank you for any help!

Comment: 1) Looking at the plot for the first-differences, it does not seem to be a non-stationary seasonal pattern; the seasonal differencing filter does not look appropriate. 2) In addition to the AIC, you should look at the ACF and PACF of the residuals from lower order ARIMA models and see if there is any structure remaining to be added to your model. 3) The ACF and PACF of the original series may also be worth a look.

Comment: looks like another question ..... http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123704/sarima-coefficients-check